# Repeat XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Before i ask here, i already search for my problem, but i still not find an answer, it could be my mistake or other thing that i do wrong.

The problem is that i want to make an `XMLHttpRequest` request to `localhost` server, but after the request done, i want to make a same `XMLHttpRequest` request to the same target/url sample as below `action/g`

```
req.repeat = function(rnd = null) {
    if(rnd == null) {
        rnd = getrandint();
    }

    var data;

    data = new FormData();
    data.append('data', 'hay');

    if(isset(xhr[rnd]) && xhr[rnd] == window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr[rnd].abort();
    }

    xhr[rnd] = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr[rnd].open('POST', url+'action/g', true);
    xhr[rnd].onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(this.readyState == 4) {
            req.repeat(rnd);
        }
    }
    xhr[rnd].send(data);
}
```

I guess the code is running well, but if the `XMLHttpRequest` request only took 10ms to get the response from the server, then the function will repeating rapidlly in every 10ms.

I try to handle this using `setTimeout()` before executing the `req.repeat()` again, but i guess that was'nt the correct one. Cause, if the `XMLHttpRequest` request took 3000ms and i add `setTimeout()` with 1000ms, then the `XMLHttpRequest` will only repeat every 4000ms which it was to slow for me.

I want to make the repeating constantly at 1000ms, if the `XMLHttpRequest` request took 1200ms to take the response from server, which larger than 1000ms the repeat will execute immidietly.

But i dont find a way, even using `setInterval()`.

for info
`var xhr = new Array();` in outer of the function.

Please help, any suggestion i apreciate

Comment: If you want to poll that frequently, you should probably stop polling and switch to Web Sockets.

Comment: using web socket? alright i will check it

Comment: did websocket need any requirement like plugin or something?

Comment: No, modern browsers have native support for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already find an answer for my own question, without using any websocket, here the code.

```
req.repeat = function(code = 0) {
    var time;
    var code, parent;

    time = new Array();
    while(code == 0) {
        code = getrandint();
    }

    return {
        execute: function(par, url, fun) {
            var data, lim;

            lim = 1500; // in miliseconds

            data = new FormData();
            data.append('data', par);

            if(xhr[code] == window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xhr[code].abort();
            }

            xhr[code] = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr[code].open('POST', meurl+'url', true);
            xhr[code].onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(xhr[code].readyState == 4) {
                    time['last'] = new Date();
                    time['diff'] = time['last'].getTime()-time['begin'].getTime();

                    if(isfun(fun)) {
                        fun(xhr[code]);
                    }

                    parent = new req.repeat(code);

                    if(time['diff'] > lim) {
                        parent.execute(par, url, fun);
                    } else {
                        tim = setTimeout(function() {
                            parent.execute(par, url, fun);
                        }, lim-time['diff']);
                    }
                }
            }
            time['begin'] = new Date();
            xhr[code].send(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help, but as i read websocket are better to do the job, but i still learning about websocket solution to my problem.